# How do I determine a file's content type in .NET?

Tags: .net, file, file-io, content-type, mime-types

My WPF application gets a file from the user with Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog()...

```
Private Sub ButtonUpload_Click(...)
    Dim FileOpenStream As Stream = Nothing
    Dim FileBox As New Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog()
    FileBox.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
    FileBox.Filter = "Pictures (*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png)|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png|" & _
                     "Documents (*.pdf;*.doc;*.docx;)|*.pdf;*.doc;*.docx;|" & _
                     "All Files (*.*)|*.*"
    FileBox.FilterIndex = 1
    FileBox.Multiselect = False
    Dim FileSelected As Nullable(Of Boolean) = FileBox.ShowDialog(Me)
    If FileSelected IsNot Nothing AndAlso FileSelected.Value = True Then
        Try
            FileOpenStream = FileBox.OpenFile()
            If (FileOpenStream IsNot Nothing) Then
                Dim ByteArray As Byte()
                Using br As New BinaryReader(FileOpenStream)
                    ByteArray = br.ReadBytes(FileOpenStream.Length)
                End Using
                Dim z As New ZackFile
                z.Id = Guid.NewGuid
                z.FileData = ByteArray
                z.FileSize = CInt(ByteArray.Length)
                z.FileName = FileBox.FileName.Split("\").Last
                z.DateAdded = Now
                db.AddToZackFile(z)
                db.SaveChanges()
            End If
        Catch Ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot read file from disk. " & Ex.Message, "Fail", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error)
        Finally
            If (FileOpenStream IsNot Nothing) Then
                FileOpenStream.Close()
            End If
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

And my ASP.NET MVC application serves it up for download at a web site with FileStreamResult()...

```
Public Class ZackFileController
    Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

    Function Display(ByVal id As Guid) As FileStreamResult
        Dim db As New EfrDotOrgEntities
        Dim Model As ZackFile = (From z As ZackFile In db.ZackFile _
                                Where z.Id = id _
                                Select z).First
        Dim ByteArray As Byte() = Model.ImageData
        Dim FileStream As System.IO.MemoryStream = New System.IO.MemoryStream(ByteArray)
        Dim ContentType As String = ?????
        Dim f As New FileStreamResult(FileStream, ContentType)
        f.FileDownloadName = Model.FileName
        Return f
    End Function

End Class
```

But FileStreamResult() needs a content type string.  How do I know the correct content type of my file?

Comment: How is the Display function used inside the page?

Comment: There is no page.  That's an ASP.NET MVC controller class.  Display is one of its Views.  But, because this View returns a FileStreamResult rather than a ViewResult, it has no ASPX page.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've replaced the FileExtension column in my database table with a ContentType column.

I populate it when I upload a file.

```
Private Sub ButtonUpload_Click(...)
    ...
    Dim FileExtension As String = "." + FileBox.FileName.Split(".").Last.ToLower
    z.ContentType = ContentType(FileExtension)
    ...
End Sub
```

I determine the content type with this function:

```
Function ContentType(ByVal FileExtension As String) As String
    Dim d As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    'Images'
    d.Add(".bmp", "image/bmp")
    d.Add(".gif", "image/gif")
    d.Add(".jpeg", "image/jpeg")
    d.Add(".jpg", "image/jpeg")
    d.Add(".png", "image/png")
    d.Add(".tif", "image/tiff")
    d.Add(".tiff", "image/tiff")
    'Documents'
    d.Add(".doc", "application/msword")
    d.Add(".docx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")
    d.Add(".pdf", "application/pdf")
    'Slideshows'
    d.Add(".ppt", "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint")
    d.Add(".pptx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation")
    'Data'
    d.Add(".xlsx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
    d.Add(".xls", "application/vnd.ms-excel")
    d.Add(".csv", "text/csv")
    d.Add(".xml", "text/xml")
    d.Add(".txt", "text/plain")
    'Compressed Folders'
    d.Add(".zip", "application/zip")
    'Audio'
    d.Add(".ogg", "application/ogg")
    d.Add(".mp3", "audio/mpeg")
    d.Add(".wma", "audio/x-ms-wma")
    d.Add(".wav", "audio/x-wav")
    'Video'
    d.Add(".wmv", "audio/x-ms-wmv")
    d.Add(".swf", "application/x-shockwave-flash")
    d.Add(".avi", "video/avi")
    d.Add(".mp4", "video/mp4")
    d.Add(".mpeg", "video/mpeg")
    d.Add(".mpg", "video/mpeg")
    d.Add(".qt", "video/quicktime")
    Return d(FileExtension)
End Function
```

This works, but it seems inelegant.

Comment: You probably ought to use a switch statement rather than building a new dictionary every time you call `ContentType`. Also, there's a `Path.GetExtension` method so you don't have to split the file name manually.

Comment: VB.Net 10 is a little nicer... Dim d As New Dictionary(Of String, String) From {
    {".bmp", "image/bmp"},
    {".gif", "image/gif"},
    {".jpeg", "image/jpeg"}} 'etc

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, or keep a single static dictionary. If the method is frequently used and supports that much of file extensions, I think it will be speed things up a little

Comment: @IvayloSlavov: A dictionary may be a good idea, especially if you want the list of supported extensions to be dynamic, or have it loaded in from a config file or something. But it won't be faster. The compiler is smart enough to implement a switch statement using a dictionary, or some other structure depending on how it thinks it will get better performance.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, yep, you've got a point on this, the compiler is able to do some white magic with the final code. Still, I'd choose a dictionary, because it will provide me with a little more flexibility than a switch statement, and I can fill it with external data, maybe coming from a configuration or database.

Comment: You can save quite a few characters by using `d(".csv") = "text/csv"` instead.

Answer (score 20):

There is a MimeMapping class in .NET 4.5

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mimemapping.aspx

Comment: Brilliant, much better than me pulling information down and creating a MimeMapping table myself.

Comment: But...the MimeMapping class in .NET simply maps to the extension given in the filename string. It doesn't check the magic bytes.

Answer (score 8):

I made a C# helper class based on Zacks response.

```
/// <summary>
/// Helps with Mime Types
/// </summary>
public static class MimeTypesHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the content type based on the given file extension
    /// </summary>
    public static string GetContentType(string fileExtension)
    {
        var mimeTypes = new Dictionary<String, String>
            {
                {".bmp", "image/bmp"},
                {".gif", "image/gif"},
                {".jpeg", "image/jpeg"},
                {".jpg", "image/jpeg"},
                {".png", "image/png"},
                {".tif", "image/tiff"},
                {".tiff", "image/tiff"},
                {".doc", "application/msword"},
                {".docx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"},
                {".pdf", "application/pdf"},
                {".ppt", "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"},
                {".pptx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation"},
                {".xlsx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"},
                {".xls", "application/vnd.ms-excel"},
                {".csv", "text/csv"},
                {".xml", "text/xml"},
                {".txt", "text/plain"},
                {".zip", "application/zip"},
                {".ogg", "application/ogg"},
                {".mp3", "audio/mpeg"},
                {".wma", "audio/x-ms-wma"},
                {".wav", "audio/x-wav"},
                {".wmv", "audio/x-ms-wmv"},
                {".swf", "application/x-shockwave-flash"},
                {".avi", "video/avi"},
                {".mp4", "video/mp4"},
                {".mpeg", "video/mpeg"},
                {".mpg", "video/mpeg"},
                {".qt", "video/quicktime"}
            };

        // if the file type is not recognized, return "application/octet-stream" so the browser will simply download it
        return mimeTypes.ContainsKey(fileExtension) ? mimeTypes[fileExtension] : "application/octet-stream";
    }
}
```

You might, of course, want to keep the `mimeTypes` alive for future queries. This is just a starting point.

Answer (score 4):

I use a custom config section in web.config (I leave the task for writing the custom configuration section to you):

```
<configSections>
    <section name="mimeTypeMappings" type="MySoftwareLol.MimeTypeMappingSection, MySoftwareLol"/>
</configSections>

<mimeTypeMappings>
    <MimeTypes>
      <MimeType Type="application/mac-binhex40" Extensions=".hqx"/>
      <MimeType Type="application/msword" Extensions=".doc"/>
      <MimeType Type="application/pdf" Extensions=".pdf"/>
      <MimeType Type="application/postscript" Extensions=".ai;.eps;.ps"/>
      <MimeType Type="application/rtf" Extensions=".rtf"/>
      <MimeType Type="application/vnd.ms-excel" Extensions=".xla;.xlc;.xlm;.xls;.xlt;.xlw"/>
      <MimeType Type="application/vnd.ms-outlook" Extensions=".msg"/>
      <MimeType Type="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint" Extensions=".pot;.pps;.ppt"/>
      <MimeType Type="application/vnd.ms-works" Extensions=".wcm;.wdb;.wks;.wps"/>
      <MimeType Type="application/x-compress" Extensions=".z"/>
      <MimeType Type="application/x-compressed" Extensions=".tgz"/>
      <MimeType Type="application/x-gzip" Extensions=".gz"/>
      <MimeType Type="application/x-msaccess" Extensions=".mdb"/>
      <MimeType Type="application/x-msmetafile" Extensions=".wmf"/>
      <MimeType Type="application/x-mspublisher" Extensions=".pub"/>
      <MimeType Type="application/x-msschedule" Extensions=".scd"/>
      <MimeType Type="application/x-msterminal" Extensions=".trm"/>
      <MimeType Type="application/x-mswrite" Extensions=".wri"/>
      <MimeType Type="application/x-tar" Extensions=".tar"/>
      <MimeType Type="application/zip" Extensions=".zip"/>
      <MimeType Type="audio/basic" Extensions=".au;.snd"/>
      <MimeType Type="audio/mid" Extensions=".mid;.rmi"/>
      <MimeType Type="audio/mpeg" Extensions=".mp3"/>
      <MimeType Type="audio/x-aiff" Extensions=".aif;.aifc;.aiff"/>
      <MimeType Type="audio/x-pn-realaudio" Extensions=".ra;.ram"/>
      <MimeType Type="audio/x-wav" Extensions=".wav"/>
      <MimeType Type="image/bmp" Extensions=".bmp"/>
      <MimeType Type="image/gif" Extensions=".gif"/>
      <MimeType Type="image/jpeg" Extensions=".jpe;.jpeg;.jpg"/>
      <MimeType Type="image/pipeg" Extensions=".jfif"/>
      <MimeType Type="image/tiff" Extensions=".tif;.tiff"/>
      <!--By default, sends HTML documents as plain text; sending it as text/html may pose security risks-->
      <!--If you wish to accept the risks, uncomment the following two lines and comment out the third.-->
      <!--<MimeType Type="text/html" Extensions=".mht;.html;.htm"/>-->
      <!--<MimeType Type="text/plain" Extensions=".txt"/>-->
      <MimeType Type="text/plain" Extensions=".txt;.html;.htm"/>
      <MimeType Type="text/richtext" Extensions=".rtx"/>
      <MimeType Type="text/tab-separated-values" Extensions=".tsv"/>
      <MimeType Type="video/mpeg" Extensions=".mp2;.mpa;.mpe;.mpeg;.mpg;.mpv2"/>
      <MimeType Type="video/quicktime" Extensions=".mov;.qt"/>
      <MimeType Type="video/x-la-asf" Extensions=".lsf;.lsx;.asf;.asr;.asx;"/>
      <MimeType Type="video/x-msvideo" Extensions=".avi"/>
    </MimeTypes>
  </mimeTypeMappings>
```

I use Path.GetExtension() and map that to one of the types listed in Extensions.

Answer (score 3):

can be easily done by using registry keys.

```
Dim regKey As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("extension")
If Not regKey Is Nothing Then
Dim ct As Object = regKey.GetValue("Content Type")
  If Not ct Is Nothing Then
     Return ct.ToString()
  End If
End If
```

This will produce the same result as the big list mentioned above!!!!

Comment: This should be the answer.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you still have the filename when you go to set the content type. You could pick the correct mime type for the file extension, or default to something like "application/base64".

Assuming the person downloading it will be using a web browser, try to stick to the common ones: [MIME Types Known By IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775147.aspx#Known_MimeTypes)

Comment: This isn't reliable enough for anything that's going to go through pen testing. I could upload a .exe renamed to .docx using this example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [This](http://pastebin.ca/raw/3265549) list, that contains 684 file extensions.

In this list every **pair** is separated by "~", and every pair has the extension name and the content type separated by "#".

I dont know what language are you using but this is in vb.net

How to use it:

1. Add a string resource to you project that contains the list.
   It will look like this - [image]
2. Add this class to your project (that will parse the string to Dictionary)

   ```
   Public Class MIMETypeList
       Public data As Dictionary(Of String, String)
       Public Sub New()
          data = New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
          Dim Temp() As String
          For Each TypeConvertion As String In My.Resources.MimeType.Split("~")
              Temp = TypeConvertion.Split("#")
              If Not data.ContainsKey(Temp(0)) Then
                  data.Add(Temp(0), Temp(1))
              End If
          Next
       End Sub
   End Class
   ```
3. Now you can use it like this:

   ```
   Dim FileExtension1 As String = ".mp4"
   Dim FileExtension2 As String = ".html"
   Dim FileExtension3 As String = ".Random"
   Dim Converter As New MIMETypeList
   If Converter.data.ContainsKey(FileExtension1) Then
       Debug.WriteLine(FileExtension1 & " -> " & Converter.data.Item(FileExtension1))
   Else
       Debug.WriteLine(FileExtension1 & " -> File Content Not Found")
   End If
   If Converter.data.ContainsKey(FileExtension2) Then
       Debug.WriteLine(FileExtension2 & " -> " & Converter.data.Item(FileExtension2))
   Else
       Debug.WriteLine(FileExtension2 & " -> File Content Not Found")
   End If
   If Converter.data.ContainsKey(FileExtension3) Then
       Debug.WriteLine(FileExtension3 & " -> " & Converter.data.Item(FileExtension3))
   Else
       Debug.WriteLine(FileExtension3 & " -> File Content Not Found")
   End If
   ```

   Output:

   .mp4 -> video/mp4

   .html -> text/html

   .Random -> File Content Not Found